# Billingsley "Probability and Measure" on constructing $\sigma$-fields

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm starting to read, very slowly, Patrick Billingsley's "Probability and Measure".  in chapter 1 "Probability", section 2 "Probability Measures", there's an optional section "Constructing $\sigma$-fields".  i'm struggling with something (located on page 31 of the 3rd edition, near location 1470 in the Kindle "anniversary" version).

For context (though probably you will really need the text in front of you): this section is trying to show that starting from the "rational" intervals $I_0$ in (0,1], plus the empty set, and then going to a lot of effort forming countable unions of those intervals, complements of them, iterating over and over again, one *still* won't end up with the Borel set, $\sigma(I_0)$, the "smallest $\sigma$-field containing $I_0$" - there will still be bits and pieces missing.

In doing this, Billingsley creates a set $B := \{\omega : \omega \notin \phi(\omega)\}$ (where the universe is $(0,1]$).  he then goes on to show that *no* element of B is contained in the set created in my previous paragraph, but that every element of B *is* in the Borel set, i.e., in $\sigma(I_0)$.

(i apologize, but i don't think i can usefully summarize $\phi()$, though if someone asks, i can try; if you're willing/interested to help, you'll probably have the book to hand.)

My question is this: how do we know that $B$ is non-empty? I apologize if this is blazingly obvious.

(in getting to this point, Billingsley creates a 2-dimensional matrix of indices to use in his iterative procedures -- which makes me wonder if there isn't some sort of diagonal argument we can use to show that $B$ contains at least one element.  but, if there is, i don't see it.)

Answer (score 2):

After defining $B$, Billingsley immediately proves that $B\notin\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathscr I_n$. But $\varnothing\in\mathscr I_0$; see the bottom of p. 30. Hence, $B\neq\varnothing$.